# Вывод записей которых нет внутри другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

Всех приветствую !
У меня есть две таблицы (A , B) , в них находятся два одинаковых столбца (column1,column2)
Мне нужно вывести записи столбцов column1 && columnd2 таблицы A, которых нет в таблице B.
Пытался использовать конкатенацию, пока безуспешно по типу:

```
select distinct concat(medium,' ',source) as match1 from leads
```

Пример записи из таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Уточнение** : column1 && column2 по сути как ключ=>значение, то есть мне нужны уникальные записи этой пары столбцов.

Подскажите как выполнить данный запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, колонки взаимосвязаны. Тогда могу предложить через встроенный запрос с несколькими переменными:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM A
WHERE (column1, column2) not IN 
(SELECT column1, column2
FROM B)
```

Проверил работу на совем примере.
Проверьте, дайте знать, получили, что хотели?

Comment: Сергей, спасибо вам !